# JavaScript validate input doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate that when pressing a button it is validated if the input, in case it is empty, an `alert` appears and that it focuses on that `input`, but what happens is that if it is empty, the `alert` comes out but sends me to another page.

**Form:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>prueba</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form onsubmit="control()" action="https://stackoverflow.com">
    <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="Ingrese usuario..." name="uname">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña..." name="psw">
    <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    function control() {
      if (document.getElementById('uname') == "") {
        alert("El campo no puede estar vacío.");
        document.getElementById('uname').focus();
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The script doesn't work 'cause when i press the button and input text is empty this no shows the alert and redirect me to page. Any sugerence?

Comment: onsubmit="return control()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if statement to the following so you actually check if the 'value' of the field is empty. As it stands you're checking if the DOMElement is equal to ""

```
   if (document.getElementById('uname').value == "") {
```

Comment: Finally, the answer is here and is correct. thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well. This will check onblur field by field.

```js
var validating = false; 
function control(element) {
  var id = element.id;

  var errors = {
      psw : 'enter password',
      uname : 'enter Username'
  };
if (document.getElementById(id).value === '') {
    if (id in errors) {
      if(validating == false) {
        validating = true
        alert(errors[id]);
        setTimeout(function(){
          document.getElementById(id).focus();
          validating = false;
        }, 1);
     }
    }
}
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>prueba</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="https://stackoverflow.com" >
        <input id="uname" name="uname" value="" type="text" onblur="control(this)" autocomplete='off'>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña..." name="psw" id="psw" value=""  onblur="control(this)" autocomplete='off' >
                    <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```